# ANTLR4 - Parser's testcases are not working

Tags: parsing, computer-science, antlr4, lexer

I try to write some parser rules for my assignment. In the assignment, we need to do the part "variable declaration" with some types. I had tried successfully with all types. For example:

> int i;

or:

> boolean bc;

But it does not work with the Array type. For example:

> int a[5];

Here is the code I wrote:

```
vardecl: pritype id (COMMA id)* SEMI ;
pritype: INTTYPE | BOOLEANTYPE | FLOATTYPE | STRINGTYPE ;
id: ID | ID LSB INTLIT RSB ;

INTTYPE: 'int' ;
BOOLEANTYPE: 'boolean' ;
FLOATTYPE: 'float' ;
STRINGTYPE: 'string' ;
ID: [_a-zA-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
INTLIT: [0-9]+ -> type(INTTYPE) ;
LSB: '[' ;
RSB: ']' ;
COMMA: ',' ;
SEMI: ';' ;
```

Can you show me what I did wrong in order for the Array type to work. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution was very close, but channeling `INTLIT` to another channel was causing problems.  I simplified it a bit and added handling for whitespace. But I added an `array` rule that will allow you to more easily handle this construct in your visitor or listener:

```
grammar Vardecl;
vardecl: pritype id (COMMA id)* SEMI ;
pritype: INTTYPE | BOOLEANTYPE | FLOATTYPE | STRINGTYPE ;
id: ID | ID array ;
array : LSB INTLIT RSB;
INTTYPE: 'int' ;
BOOLEANTYPE: 'boolean' ;
FLOATTYPE: 'float' ;
STRINGTYPE: 'string' ;
ID: [_a-zA-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
INTLIT: [0-9]+ ;
LSB: '[' ;
RSB: ']' ;
COMMA: ',' ;
SEMI: ';' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

With this input:

```
int i[5], a[10];
```

You get this lexer tokenization:

```
[@0,0:2='int',<'int'>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='i',<ID>,1:4]
[@2,5:5='[',<'['>,1:5]
[@3,6:6='5',<INTLIT>,1:6]
[@4,7:7=']',<']'>,1:7]
[@5,8:8=',',<','>,1:8]
[@6,10:10='a',<ID>,1:10]
[@7,11:11='[',<'['>,1:11]
[@8,12:13='10',<INTLIT>,1:12]
[@9,14:14=']',<']'>,1:14]
[@10,15:15=';',<';'>,1:15]
[@11,16:15='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:16]
```

And this parse tree:

[image]

So I think you're good to go now.

Comment: Thanks alot @Tom, you're right. Your solution is very clear. I wish that I could realize it sooner.

Comment: @DeenThatcher Glad you found my solution helpful!  You could accept it as a way to reward that and help others find it.  [Please take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)